# Python: create nested list from equation results

Tags: python, list, nested-loops

I am very new to Python programming, and I am trying to get my quadratic equation solver to "collect" the answers for x1 and x2 into a nested list.

It solves the equation fine with correct results, and I am able to get the results presented like I want them, but I am not able to gather them into the same list at the end of the loop. Code below:

```
from math import sqrt

abcList = [[1, 2, 1], [9, 12, 4], [1, -7, 0], [1, -2, -3]]

for abc in abcList:
    a, b, c = abc
    q = b**2 - 4*a*c

    if q > 0:
        q_sqrt = sqrt(q)
        x1 = (-b + q_sqrt)/(2*a)
        x2 = (-b - q_sqrt)/(2*a)

    elif q == 0:
        x1 = -b/(2*a)
        x2 = x1

    else:
        raise ValueError("q is negative.")

    resultList = []

    print ('x1 = ', x1)

    resultList.append(x1)

    print ('x2 = ', x2)

    resultList.append(x2)

    #print ('a = ', a, ', b = ', b, 'and c = ',c)

    print (resultList)

print ('-----')
```

This is the result I get:

```
x1 =  -1.0
x2 =  -1.0
[-1.0, -1.0]
x1 =  -0.6666666666666666
x2 =  -0.6666666666666666
[-0.6666666666666666, -0.6666666666666666]
x1 =  7.0
x2 =  0.0
[7.0, 0.0]
x1 =  3.0
x2 =  -1.0
[3.0, -1.0]
-----
```

This is the result I want:

```
x1 =  -1.0
x2 =  -1.0

x1 =  -0.6666666666666666
x2 =  -0.6666666666666666

x1 =  7.0
x2 =  0.0

x1 =  3.0
x2 =  -1.0


[[-1.0, -1.0], [-0.6666666666666666, -0.6666666666666666], [7.0, 0.0], [3.0, -1.0]]
-----
```

Comment: dedent the line `print (resultList)` to have the same indent as the `print('-----')`. (Voting to close as unlikely to help others)

Comment: Well presented question.

Answer (score 2):

You just need to reorganize your code slightly. Initialize `resultList` outside the `for` loop, and append each pair of answers as a 2 element list.

```
    from math import sqrt

    abcList = [[1, 2, 1], [9, 12, 4], [1, -7, 0], [1, -2, -3]]
    resultList = []

    for abc in abcList:
        a, b, c = abc
        q = b**2 - 4*a*c

        if q > 0:
            q_sqrt = sqrt(q)
            x1 = (-b + q_sqrt)/(2*a)
            x2 = (-b - q_sqrt)/(2*a)
        elif q == 0:
            x1 = -b/(2*a)
            x2 = x1
        else:
            raise ValueError("q is negative.")

        #print ('a = ', a, ', b = ', b, 'and c = ',c)
        print ('x1 = ', x1)
        print ('x2 = ', x2)
        resultList.append([x1, x2])

    print (resultList)        
    print ('-----')
```

**output**

```
x1 =  -1.0
x2 =  -1.0
x1 =  -0.666666666667
x2 =  -0.666666666667
x1 =  7.0
x2 =  0.0
x1 =  3.0
x2 =  -1.0
[[-1.0, -1.0], [-0.66666666666666663, -0.66666666666666663], [7.0, 0.0], [3.0, -1.0]]
-----
```

BTW, there's no need to import the `math` module just to do square roots: you can use the `**` exponentiation operator, which is more efficient than making a function call.

```
q_sqrt = q ** 0.5
```

Answer (score 1):

Your problem is that you are trying to append individual components to the result list and that you are printing it out at each iteration of the loop.
The resultList has to be outside your loop and x1 and x2 have to be appended as a pair to the resultList. Please see below:

```
from math import sqrt

abcList = [[1, 2, 1], [9, 12, 4], [1, -7, 0], [1, -2, -3]]

resultList = []

for abc in abcList:
    a, b, c = abc
    q = b**2 - 4*a*c

    if q > 0:
        q_sqrt = sqrt(q)
        x1 = (-b + q_sqrt)/(2*a)
        x2 = (-b - q_sqrt)/(2*a)

    elif q == 0:
        x1 = -b/(2*a)
        x2 = x1

    else:
        raise ValueError("q is negative.")


    print ('x1 = ', x1)

    print ('x2 = ', x2)

    resultList.append( [x1, x2] )

    #print ('a = ', a, ', b = ', b, 'and c = ',c)

print (resultList)

print ('-----')
```